# iOS - How do I pass arguments from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to a viewController?

Tags: ios, delegates, uiviewcontroller

I want to know how can I pass arguments from the delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to the first view controller whose view will be launched.

I didn`t find anything similar on the Internet.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[myViewController setMyCoolFirstArgument: coolArgument];
[myViewController setMyCoolSecondArgument: coolSecondArgument];
[window setRootViewController: myViewController];
```

and in `MyViewController.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CoolArgument *myCoolFirstArgument;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CoolArgument *myCoolSecondArgument;
```

and in `MyViewController.m`

```
@synthesize myCoolFirstArgument, myCoolSecondArgument;
```